# Combining "display: inline-block" with "position: absolute": what should happen?

Tags: css, firefox

The IE and WebKit browsers seem to agree that "position: absolute" when applied to "display: inline-block" (or, in the case of IE7, simple "inline" elements with "hasLayout" set) should result in blocks positioned inline.  That is, with:

```
Hello there <label style='position: absolute; display: inline-block'>sir</label>
```

those browsers will show:

```
Hello theresir
```

or

```
Hello there sir
```

However, Firefox (3 and up, I think) will give this:

```
Hello there
sir
```

That is, they make the "inline-block" element start on a new line. Now, that's clearly not what "inline-block" does *without* being combined with "position: absolute", nor is it what "position: absolute" does without "display: inline-block". Is this a bug, or just a bad (ambiguous) spec?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mqSH7/2/) is a very simple jsfiddle.

(*edit* — maybe that **is** what Firefox does with "position: absolute" and no "display" setting ...)

Comment: `position: absolute` should force `display: block`. See number 2 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). I'm not sure what's going on here..

Comment: Hmm ... that suggests that Firefox is right and everybody else is wrong ...

Comment: Opera behaves in the same way as Firefox, so I'm inclined to agree with you. A WebKit bug and an IE bug?

Comment: Yes, OK then. It's kind of a drag because it'd really make "position: absolute" more useful if it worked with inline content, but I can understand that sometimes that'd be intractable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right behavior here is not actually defined in the spec.  The vertical position should be "as if the position were not absolute, sort of", basically.  More precisely, this part of http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height is relevant:

> But rather than actually calculating the dimensions of that
>   hypothetical box, user agents are free to make a guess at its probable
>   position.

That said, the Gecko code implementing this predates Gecko's implementation of inline-block, so only checks for original display being "inline".  I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674435 to look into changing this in Gecko.

Comment: wow you seem to actually know stuff, and that's pretty cool :-)

Comment: also what you said about the implementation matches my suspicion :-)

Comment: @Pointy Knowing this stuff is sort of my day job.  ;)

Comment: Is [number 2 here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) not always true? Does it not apply because none of top/right/bottom/left is set?

Comment: @thirtydot That clause applies and sets display to `block`.  But yes, since the values of top/right/bottom/left are all `auto` the actual positioning ends up depending on the hypothetical box position.